# Convert enum value by field

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I'm using reactive MongoDB in spring.
Here is the Enum Language:

```
public enum Language {
    ARABIC("ar"),
    UZBEK("uz");

    private final String code;

    Language(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public static Language getLanguage(String codeString) {
        return Stream.of(Language.values())
                .filter(code -> codeString.equals(code.getCode()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

Here are the converters:

```
@ReadingConverter
public class EnumReadingConverter implements Converter<String, Language> {

    @Override
    public Language convert(String source) {
        return Language.getLanguage(source);
    }
}
```

```
@WritingConverter
public class EnumWritingConverter implements Converter<Language, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(Language source) {
        return source.getCode();
    }
}
```

Problem:
When I write to the database it is writing `Language` enum as `"ARABIC"` or `"UZBEK"` anyway. It should write as `"uz"` or `"ar"`. Why is not saving like this?

Comment: @Smutje it is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Everything was right except, I forgot to register converters like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDBConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions(){
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
        converterList.add(new EnumReadingConverter());
        converterList.add(new EnumWritingConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converterList);
    }
}
```

Thanks [Smutje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3296621/smutje) for the advice!